# convergence in probability ecpected value limit

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I have to show that if $X_n$ is a sequence of bounded almost surely random variables than it holds that $X_n$ converge in probability to $0$ if and only if $\lim E(X_n)=0$  ($E$ is expected value)

so, to show backwards implication ( <- ) is easy, cause $\lim E(X_n)=0$ is by definition convergence in first moment to $0$ so, it must follow that if $\lim E(X_n)=0$ implies $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

But I am struggling to show ( -> ). Maybe somebody will know the answer.

Comment: Note also that the implication '' if $\lim\mathbb EX_n=0$ and $X_n$ are bounded a.s. then $X_n\xrightarrow{p} 0$'' is obviously wrong. For counterexample you can take a sequence of r.v. with values $\pm 1$ with probabilities $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|X_n|\leq C$ a.s. and $X_n\xrightarrow{p} 0$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$
$$
|\mathbb E(X_n)|\leq \mathbb E(|X_n|) = \mathbb E(|X_n|\cdot I(|X_n|<\varepsilon))+\mathbb E(|X_n|\cdot I(|X_n|\geq\varepsilon)) 
$$
$$
\leq \mathbb E(\varepsilon\cdot I(|X_n|<\varepsilon))+\mathbb E(C\cdot I(|X_n|\geq\varepsilon)) \leq \varepsilon + C\mathbb P(|X_n|\geq\varepsilon)\to \varepsilon
$$
as $n\to\infty$. So for every $\varepsilon>0$
$$
0\leq \limsup |\mathbb E(X_n)|\leq \varepsilon.
$$
Then $\lim |\mathbb E(X_n)|=0$.